# How to get the refrence of the current image in image slider-javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get the detail of the image element which is currently previewed to user when they are navigating to the images with the slider.

slider.html:-

```
    <div class="pop-box">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides2 fade">

      <img src="img/challenge-image.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">

      <img src="img/challenger-participation.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">

      <img src="img/banner.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides2 fade">

      <img src="img/img-1.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <img src="img/img-2.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <img src="img/img-3.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <img src="img/people-first.jpg">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>




    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides2(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides2(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    </div>
```

So what i want is when users click prev or next button then they will get a preview of some image from the above list i just want to get the detail of that image element on every instant of click.

My slider.js:-

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides2(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides2(n) {
    showSlides2(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide2(n) {
    showSlides2(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides2(n) {

    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found that I have half solution in my question I just need to add this piece of code in my slider.js

```
var ImgElement = slides[slideIndex-1].children[0];
```

this Will give me the exact image element which I want.Since my slider.js:-

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";
```

So in my actual html code i have different images which is under class `myslides2` ,and what i have done in my slider.js is i have added `style :"none"` while iterating over my images and after the loop ends i added `stye:"flex"` to the last `div`,and this is my target div which contain my desired image so finally i have done this by getting its childeren which is the first element of array.since getting any element by classname returns a list,so that's why i have done in this way.